# how to import csv data in to Postgres table?

Tags: postgresql, import-from-csv

Here is the query:

```
COPY public.project(project_number,project_name,country) from '\\server\csv\projects_export.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

The result of this query is:

```
 ERROR:  could not open file "\\server\csv\projects_export.csv" 
 for reading: No such file or directory.
```

please guide me

Comment: yes the file is located in the server, and the postgre query also run through server so will u gudime me how?

Comment: Winged Panther, that question is about a confusion of `psql` console vs. SQL commands. This one appears to be an unrelated issue with quoting of backslashes in Windows filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape/double backslash characters in single quoted string literals. This is a common issue with literal Windows filenames. The docs for `COPY` **specifically warn about this**: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html

[Dollar quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) is the simplest alternative:

```
COPY public.project(project_number,project_name,country) from $$\\server\Softwel\Projects\projects\csv\projects_export.csv$$ DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```